# How to write mysql query into PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Appreciate if you could help me to write below mysql code to PDO statement.

```
     $sql  = "SELECT * FROM node WHERE node_name='$nodename'";

     $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

when I read on PDO::query Manual i found this code

```
      <?php
      $connection = new pdo("sqlite:file.sq3");
      $query="SELECT * FROM table";
      $result = $connection->query($query);
      $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      print_r($row);
      ?>
```

what is the function for "sqlite:file.sq3" and "(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you connect to the database like this :

```
try {
$db = new PDO("sqlite:file.sq3");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo 'Error : <br>' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

> **PS: You dont need the try and the catch, but we used to get the error and handle it in a nice way as we want to**

and next we query like this :

```
 $db->query(SELECT * FROM node WHERE node_name='$nodename'");
```

and we fetch it like this :

```
 $query = $db->query(SELECT * FROM node WHERE node_name='$nodename'");
 $row   = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

and now you use `$row->name` for example

here is more about PDO::FETCH

> - **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC**: returns an array indexed by column name as returned    in your result set
> - **PDO::FETCH_BOTH** (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result    set
> - **PDO::FETCH_BOUND**: returns TRUE and assigns the values of the columns in your result set to the PHP variables to which they were
>     bound with the PDOStatement::bindColumn() method
> - **PDO::FETCH_CLASS**: returns a new instance of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the
>     class. If fetch_style includes PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g.
>     **PDO::FETCH_CLASS** | **PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE)** then the name of the class
>     is determined from a value of the first column.
> - **PDO::FETCH_INTO**: updates an existing instance of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in
>     the class
> - **PDO::FETCH_LAZY**: combines PDO::FETCH_BOTH and PDO::FETCH_OBJ, creating the object variable names as they are accessed
> - **PDO::FETCH_NUM**: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0
> - **PDO::FETCH_OBJ**: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set

Answer (score 0):

That line points to your sql file, there is no function for it. It opens a PDO connection and you can query further.

```
$connection = new pdo("sqlite:/path/to/sql/file.sq3");
```

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` tells the function `fetch()` to pull associative array from table.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using MySQL before, I don't think the sqlite DSN is correct for you.  SQLite is a different brand of RDBMS, and it's not compatible with MySQL.

To use PDO to connect to MySQL, see this manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Example:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```